# Strange error in rails while sending notification email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to send a notification email to the email provided by the user when he clicks the place order button but i get this error

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

and the error is in order_controller.rb file here it is

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @order_form=OrderForm.new(user: User.new(order_params[:user]),cart: @cart)
        if @order_form.save
            notify_user
            redirect_to root_path,notice:"Thank You for placing the order sir."
        else
        render "carts/checkout"
        end
    end

   private

    def notify_user
      OrderMailer.order_confirmation(@order_form.order).deliver  
    end

    def order_params
        params.require(:order_form).permit(
            user:[:name,:phone,:address,:city,:country,:postal_code,:email])
    end
end
```

and this is the order_form.rb model

```
class OrderForm
    include ActiveModel::Model
    attr_accessor :user,:order
    attr_writer :cart
    def save
        set_password_for_user
        if valid?
            persist
            true
            else
            false
        end
    end
    def has_error?
        user.errors.any?
    end

    private
    def valid?
        user.valid?
    end

    def persist
        user.save
        @order=Order.create!(user:user)
        build_order_items
    end

    def set_password_for_user
        user.password="examplepassword"
    end

    def build_order_items
        @cart.items.each do |item|
            @order.order_items.create! product_id: item.product_id, quantity: item.quantity

        end
    end
end
```

and finally my order_mailer.rb mailer

```
class OrderMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "bobbyverma946@yahoo.in"


    def order_confirmation order
        @order=order
        mail to: order.user.email, subject: "Your order (##{order.id})"
    end
end
```

can someone please tell me whats wrong with the code because i am really confused

Comment: If you look carefully at the stack trace you should get a line reference. Which of all this code does that refer to? Normally that's treating an array as if it's a Hash.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to initialize the class variable? There is no initialize method in `OrderForm`.

Comment: Where is `@cart` defined in `#create` action?

Comment: @RubyRacer [ActiveModel::Model](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) adds the constructor for you. 
@Kris I guess he isn't showing all the code because `OrderForm` should break first in `build_order_items` because `@cart` isn't defined

Comment: your strong params may be configured incorrectly. I believe that for nested parameters (your order form is passing a :user) you need to configure them as ... params.require(:order_form).permit(:name, :age, users_attributes: [ :id, :name]).